# How take a digit number from a string from dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `Dataframe`:

```
ID      |  program  |  
--------|-----------|
53-8975 |  null     |
53-9875 |  null     |
53A7569 |           | 
53-9456 |  XXXX     |
53-9875 |           |
---------------------
```

The `ID` and the `program` are `String`. 
I want to fill all `null` or `""` in `program` column by the letter `K` and if the 4th digit in the `ID` column is `9`.
For example:

I have two ID that there 4th is 9: 53-9875 and 53-9456 and the values of program column is respectively are: `null` and `""`

How can I fill the `program` column by the letter `K` if the `4th digit` in the `ID` column is `9` and the `program` is `null` or `""` using pyspark.

To be my Dataframe:

```
ID      |  program  |  
--------|-----------|
53-8975 |  null     |
53-9875 |  K        |
53A7569 |           | 
53-9456 |  XXXX     |
53-9875 |   K       |
---------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we have your original dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("53-8975", None), ("53-9875", None), ("53A7569", ""), ("53-9456", "XXXX"), ("53-9875", "")], ["id", "program"])
df.show()
+-------+-------+
|     id|program|
+-------+-------+
|53-8975|   null|
|53-9875|   null|
|53A7569|       |
|53-9456|   XXXX|
|53-9875|       |
+-------+-------+
```

We can create a transformation that takes `program` or "k" according to your specification with `when().otherwise()`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

programNullOrEmpty = (col("program") == "") | (isnull(col("program")))
id9 = col("id").substr(4,1) == "9"

df.withColumn("program", when(programNullOrEmpty & id9, lit("K"))
                         .otherwise(col("program")))\
    .show()

+-------+-------+
|     id|program|
+-------+-------+
|53-8975|   null|
|53-9875|      K|
|53A7569|       |
|53-9456|   XXXX|
|53-9875|      K|
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, In fact I changed it like this, I used your solution: 

  output = (
        df.select(
            F.col('program'),
            F.col('ID')
            .withColumn("program", F.when((F.col("program") == "") | (isnull(F.col("program"))) & (F.col("ID").substr(4,1) == "9"), lit("K")).otherwise(F.col("program")))
            )
    )

I got this error: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
Some help please ?

Comment: There were issues with parentheses in your modifications, it should work like ```output = ( df.select( F.col('program'), F.col('ID') ).withColumn("program", F.when(((F.col("program") == "") | (F.isnull(F.col("program")))) & (F.col("ID").substr(4,1) == "9"), F.lit("K")).otherwise(F.col("program"))) ) ```

Comment: If you found the answer useful please accept the answer and optionally upvote :)